# How to have full command on time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have use carbon, but it's not working according to my needs.
What I want is to apply check on time in minutes, like after every 15 min check, to work and then minute reset to zero.

Like:

```
if(time > 15 ) {
  do this...
  reset to zero
} else {
  do this
}
```

Comment: why not you do that on your frontend probably using javascript?

Comment: Are you running a timer, or just checking to see if the minute is 0, 15, 30, or 45?

Answer (score 0):

You need task schedule or command make:
The simple form is call your controller every15min, go to app/console/Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call('yourcontroller@youtfunction')->everyFifteenMinutes();
}
```

And you run this: php artisan schedule:run

You can make command, but this ius more complex

Here is oficial documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

Comment: Can use sessions and apply condition like session expires and run my condition. But question is how to set condition on sessions as i am trying but still not working. Like config/session.php setting my lifetime and then on env but its not working. I think it will be helpful if someone let me know sessions help me out or not.